# Javascript function that puts total bytes read from csv into a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I Have a CSV file stored locally on a Web server which gets added to periodically with numeric and string data all of unequal lengths. I need a way to add up all of the rows byte values from each read, The Byte count is required because of the stateless nature of reading the file in from the server. I need to maintain the next read start point! So far I can get the byte value counted for each row,

```
            function renderData( data )
            {
                var dataRows = data.split( "\n" );
                var numrows = dataRows.length;
                var table = document.createElement("Table");
                table.border = 1;
                var nextindex = 0;
                for( i = 0; i < numrows; i++ )
                {
                    var rowlength = dataRows[i].length;
                    var totalBytes = numrows += rowlength;
                    currentindex = nextindex;
                    nextindex = totalBytes;
                    document.write(" Row "+i+" is " + rowlength + " bytes long ");
                    document.write(" next index starts " + totalBytes + " bytes in ");
                    var tableRow = table.insertRow(i);
                    var dataCells = dataRows[i].split(",");
                    for( j = 0; j <dataCells.length; j++ )
                    {
                        var tableCell= tableRow.insertCell(j);      
                        tableCell.innerHTML = dataCells[j];
                    }
                    executeSql( "INSERT INTO CAN ("", "", "", etc) values(?,?,?,)", dataCells );

                }
                document.body.appendChild( table );
            }
```

Comment: The code is incomplete. Also, please try to make this an actual question. What you have tried so far and which lines of thought you've followed would also be of help (and show that you've actually tried to solve the problem yourself). All that said, Javascript doesn't work well with binary data, so some more info on what kind of data your input is would also be of help.

Comment: My apologies, I am aware that the function is incomplete. So far I am able to open a connection to a CSV file stored locally on a web server, I can then read each row of data into a Websql database, and count how many bytes each row contains. The CSV data gets added to periodically and each data item is of un-equal length, hence the issue of using an offset or totalBytes. I need a way of jumping to a certain point in the CSV as all fileds are of unequal length I cannot just work with rows.

Comment: Presumably you read a huge chunk of data and pass it into the function through the data parameter, and at some later time you need to read from the same file, starting where you left off previously - correct? Then won't simply `data.length` be the position you need to start reading from next? Or rather, the sum of all previous `data.length` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about instead of doing `var totalbytes = numrows*nextindex`, make totalbytes a global variable and do  `totalbytes += rowlength;` each iteration ?

Comment: thanks this helped a little but now produces the following output    Row 0 is 104 bytes longnext index starts 135bytes inRow 1 is 112 bytes longnext index starts 247bytes inRow 2 is 108 bytes longnext index starts 355bytes inRow 3 is 129 bytes longnext index starts 484bytes inRow 4 is 134 bytes longnext index starts 618bytes inRow 5 is 124 bytes longnext index starts 742bytes inRow 6 is 134 bytes longnext index starts 876bytes inRow 7 is 130 bytes longnext index starts 1006bytes inRow 8 is 135 bytes longnext index starts 1141bytes inRow 9 is 124 bytes longnext index etc

Comment: These numbers don't make sense because totalBytes should be increased only by the rowlength,  ie (0, 0+104, 0+104+112, 0+104+112+108, ) so it should never become 135.  Please put the entire code in the question.

Comment: apologies, have changed code to include new totalBytes variable and it now produces the above output! the first index is 0 then then the first read should make the next index 104 not 135 I have attached the full code below.